# How to make a subtype of string in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-hooks

I making a game called risk using typescript and react hooks. The game is played on some kind of a map. So first of all I have design I `MapEditor`. The state of Map Editor is like

```
export interface IMapEditorState {
   mousePos: IPoint;
   countries: {[k: string]: ICountry};
   continents: { [k: string]: IContinent };
}
```

`countries` and `continents` are objects. The interface for country looks like

```
//The "name" property and above key will be same in `{[k: string]: ICountry};` will be same
export interface ICountry {
   name: string;
   border: IDot[];
   neighbours: string[];
   completed: boolean;
}
```

Now I make a reducer function. For all the types of action I used two props `name` and `data`. `name` will always be a `string` and data will a type depending on `name`

```
type ActionTypes = {name: "removeCountry", data: string} | {name: "addCountry", data: ICountry};
const reducer = (state: IMapEditorState, action: ActionTypes) => {
   ...
}
```

Now see the first type in `ActionTypes` which is `{name: "removeCountry", data: string}`. In the dispatch method a I will use `{name: "removeCountry"}` the compiler will force to pass `data` as `string` but **it couldn't be any string which I don't want. I want that I should only be able to pass string which is key of `{[k: string]: ICountry}` in `IMapEditorState` or the `name` in `ICountry`**.

Is there any way that I could create a subtype of a string called `CountryName` and use it

```
export interface IMapEditorState {
   mousePos: IPoint;
   countries: {[k: CountryName]: ICountry};
   continents: { [k: string]: IContinent };
}
export interface ICountry {
   name: CountryName;
   border: IDot[];
   neighbours: string[];
   completed: boolean;
}
type ActionTypes = {name: "removeCountry", data: CountryName} | {name: "addCountry", data: ICountry};
```

I will very thankful if you help me and kindly give your view on my data structure if got idea what is the game.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have created anything further. Just wanted to get a better way to further.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Consider a `function test(x : CountryName){...}`. Now here I want could only pass the `name` property of `ICountry`(For the time ignore the key of the object)

Comment: Given that the interface is `name: CountryName;`, typing `function test(x : CountryName)` should already require that the parameter is of the permitted type, a `CountryName` and nothing else, right?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I also want the keys of the `countries` to be of type `CountryName`. But if its not possible so please explain why not.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to be able to do these checks at compile time, you'll have to make a list of all possible country names:

```
type CountryName = 'cName1' | 'cName2' | 'cName3';
```

Or, if you can define an initial object of all possible countries, you can declare it as `const` (so that TS doesn't generalize its strings), and then take its keys via `keyof`:

```
const initialCountries = {
    cName1: {
        name: 'cName1',
        completed: false
        // ...
    },
    cName2: {
        name: 'cName2',
        completed: false
    },
    cName3: {
        name: 'cName3',
        completed: false
    },
} as const;
type CountryName = keyof typeof initialCountries;
```

Result for `CountryName` is `"cName1" | "cName2" | "cName3"`.

Then you can define `IMapEditorState` using the above `CountryName`:

```
export interface ICountry {
    name: CountryName;
    border: IDot[];
    neighbours: string[];
    completed: boolean;
}
export interface IMapEditorState {
    mousePos: IPoint;
    countries: { [k: CountryName]: ICountry };
    continents: { [k: string]: IContinent };
}
```

And then the following will compile:

```
const initalIMapEditorState: IMapEditorState = {
    countries: initialCountries,
    // ...
};
```

and then you can use `CountryName` wherever else you need to:

```
type ActionTypes = {name: "removeCountry", data: CountryName} | {name: "addCountry", data: ICountry};
```

Answer (score 1):

Typescript 4.1.5:

In my case I needed to mark a stringified date in this format "YYYY-MM-DD" as an ISODate rather than just a string. I used this approach, I think it's more effective than [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59907282/how-to-make-a-subtype-of-string-in-typescript/59907669#59907669) if the number of valid strings is more than just a few:

```js
interface ISODateDifferentiator extends String {
  [key: string]: unknown;
}
export type ISODate = ISODateDifferentiator & string; 

export const ValidateIsoDate = (date: string): date is ISODate => {
  return date.match(/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/) !== null;
}
```

You get the desired `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ISODate'.` when doing an unsafe assignment but can convert using the typeguard function. You also still get the string method auto-completion.

Comment: What's the point of specifying `[key: string]: unknown;` in the `ISODateDifferentiator`? Could we just use an empty interface or something else?

Comment: This doesn't seem to do much. If you have `function foo(a: ISODate)`, you can still pass any string.